Confused about eureka server functionality
when I started eureka server in spring cloud ,in the dashboard, I saw that the renew threshold is 1. Why is this at all? I did not register an instance in it that wants to take a value.

Also when I registered a client microservice in it, as it is clear in the second picture, the renew threshold value is 3. All the values ​​of my configurations are the default values, the renewed threshold should be: 60s/30s*0.85~1, which is not this case. why ?

